# Entity Framework 4 generated queries are joining full tables

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have two entities: Master and Details.
When I query them, the resulting query to database is:

```
SELECT [Extent2]."needed columns listed here", [Extent1]."needed columns listed here"
FROM (SELECT * [Details]."all columns listed here"...
     FROM [dbo].[Details] AS [Details]) AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Master] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[key] = [Extent2].[key]
WHERE [Extent1].[filterColumn] = @p__linq__0
```

My question is: why not the filter is in the inner query? How can I get this query? I've tried a lot of EF and Linq expressions.

What I need is something like:

```
SELECT <anything needed>
  FROM Master LEFT JOIN Details ON Master.key = Details.Key
 WHERE filterColumn = @param
```

I'm having a full sequential scan in both tables, and in my production environment, I have milions of rows in each table.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Can you show your LINQ statement?

Comment: Sure:

var query = from m in ctx.Master
from d in ctx.Master.Details
where d.filter1 == someVar1 && m.filter2 == someVar2
select new {m, d};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes The entity Framework does not produce the best query.  You can do a few of the following to optimize.

1. Modify the linq statement (test with
   [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/))
2. [Create a stored proc and map the stored proc to return an entity](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/03/13/mapping-stored-procedure-results-to-a-custom-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx)
3. Create a view that handles the join and map the view to a new
   entity

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm getting the same "SELECT WHOLE TABLE IN A SUBQUERY" with other statements. I noticed that if I make an expression with an where filtering both tables, the sql query has this issue.

Comment: The query optimizer got fine that query with. I had an aceptable performance. Thanks again.