# Entity Framework: AsNoTracking Kills Eager Loading of Related Objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We've been getting by w/ loading related objects using anonymous type projections and for the most part this works okay (not great, just ok; using [all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978170/entity-framework-4-generated-queries-are-joining-full-tables) is less than ideal, but what can you do).

Now we've run into a situation that requires **AsNoTracking()** but this seems to be disabling the eager loading behavior that we had w/ the anonymous types - any property access on results now trigger fresh queries.

Are these two concepts mutually exclusives?

Answer (score 2):

Lazy loading and eager loading are two different things entirely.

That said, it sounds like you're talking about fixup, which is neither of them. Hard to tell since you don't show any code. No, there is no requirement to select all columns, but, again, you don't show your code, so I can't help you fix it.

At any rate, yes, this is normal. `.AsNoTracking` means the loaded entities and anything they reference are not fixed up with other objects in memory. That's a performance win, but it means that you may end up with the "same" entity in memory more than once. So it's usually for read-only work only.

Comment: Eager loading by projecting to an anonymous type is no different than this this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996438/how-to-sort-related-entities-with-eager-loading-in-ado-net-entity-framework. Is there any way to load related objects in a single query w/ AsNoTracking enabled?

Comment: Projecting onto an anonymous type is projection, not eager loading. Projection works fine with `AsNoTracking()`, as long as you understand the difference.